# Node.js proxy and oauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, proxy

I have a small node.js application that uses oAuth quite heavily and I came into a problem: it appears that server where I want to install it is hidden behind proxy. And now: I have to rewrite part of code to use a proxy and I have a question about approach:

I'm using [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth), but I believe it doesn't support proxying. I had already overridden it a bit to support fetching binary data through oAuth, but now:

- should I clone the whole library and change it to my needs and put it inside my app
- write oauth library by myself from scratch, or
- is there a better way to solve this problem?

I would love to know how would you solve this problem in terms of maintenance in the future, good practices and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having this issue, but there is a [fork of OAuth that supports https here](https://github.com/ozten/node-oauth).